# Using different sugar for priming

Tags: sugar, priming

My brew is ready for bottling, this time I doubled the recipe and fermented two Triple Brewferm can kits. I added three cans of Lyle's golden syrup (around 1362 grams), as it gives a better taste. The total amount of the batch is around 18 litres. The OG was 1070 and the FG is now 1014, a bit higher than the predicted 1010.

Should I use the same sugar for priming? Is there a risk of ruining the batch or the taste if using a different type of sugar, i.e. granulated sugar?

Comment: I've used granulated sugar in the past. With no issues. Just did a batch with sugar cubes that will be ready in about 2 weeks. I have heard you can use many forms of sugar to carbonate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have no problem using table sugar for priming, but you can use golden syrup if you prefer.

I would say there is no risk of ruining the flavour. The amount you are using for priming will not affect the taste, yeast will convert all table sugar into CO2 and alcohol, so there will be no detecable flavour affect on your finished brew.

Comment: Thanks @Mr_road for your answer, I think I will try golden syrup this time

Comment: the problem with using the syrup is that you have to know the gravity abd fermentability of it in order to get the proper amount

Comment: I read that around 20% more of golden syrup would be the same as using normal granulated sugar. I bottled the brew last night, using the syrup and the same quantity rule. The beer is still green but the taste was really good. Many thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 2):

I only use glucose/dextrose/brewing sugar for priming - ie carbonating beer. I have never had any problems or off tastes. In theory sucrose (table sugar) should be as good but some have reported a "tangy taste" when using sucrose but that is usually lost when using invert sugar or golden syrup. . However as the amount used is relatively small I would not suppose that any real flavour issues were introduced *per se* by such sugars.

Comment: Just remember that you might want to use a bit more if using dextrose vs sucrose. Appearantly [dextrose contains 9% water by weight](http://braukaiser.com/wiki/index.php?title=Accurately_Calculating_Sugar_Additions_for_Carbonation#Corn_Sugar), which means that only 91% of its weight can be considered for the CO2 calculation. You can use a [priming sugar calculator](http://homebrewcalc.com/#PrimingSugar) if you are lazy.